# Question on showing invertibility of function $\Phi: \mathcal{L}(V,W) \to M_{m \times n}(F)$ in regards to establishing an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

My question comes from a proof of establishing that the function $\Phi: \mathcal{L}(V,W) \to M_{m\times n}(F)$ is an isomorphism. The statement of the theorem comes from *Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence*. What follows is the statement of theorem and its proof.

[image]

[image]

I understand the uniqueness portion of this proof. What I'm not grasping is how showing the existence of this matrix establishes that $\Phi$ is one-to-one and onto?

Comment: You mean the matrix $A$?

Comment: There is no assertion about the existence of any matrix. The matrix $A$ was arbitrarily chosen and what's being asserted is the existence of a furthermore unique $T$ such that $[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}=A$.

Comment: Ok. I described the understanding of the existence incorrectly. But I still don't understand how bijectivity is established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For injective: assume $\Phi(T)=0$ then
$[T]^\gamma_\beta=0 \Rightarrow T=0$.
So $N(\Phi)=\{0\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\Phi$ is injective.

For surjective: Take a matrix, define a linear transformation then how are these two the linear transformation and matrix are defined? The linear transformation must be such that the matrix of the linear transformation relative to the basis $\beta$ and $\gamma$ is the matrix that you started with.

Can you show that $\Phi$ is linear transformation?

Comment: Showing $\Phi$ is a linear transformation I can do. After reading the theorem and proof again, plus your explanation I see where I went wrong. I was forgetting that $T$ are elements in this case and not mappings.